# What are merits and demerits of splitting records in multiple table or using single table for storing multiple records in single table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to know:

1. What are the merits and demerits of splitting records in multiple table or using single table for storing multiple records in single table
2. Which approach is good for large database sites?
3. What is the execution speed of a MySql query?
4. How can I improve the performance of my query in the database?
5. What is data parsing? I heard from someone it is a kind of hacking only for Apache - MySql server. If that is so, how can I prevent it from happening (hackers write a script and all the data is downloaded from the server)

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific? What data do you want to store?
Which "mySQL query" are you interested in? What's the query you want to improve?
Also, try to ask a single question - the first two questions seem related, I could imagine the next two are part of that same question (i.e. performance is a key concern for your database design); 5 is something you might go to wikipedia for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This post is just my opinion on the matter. I may be wrong in some or more parts.**

I'll take a very, very shallow dip into what I think you're looking for; normalized and denormalized data:

Why Normalize:

- Reduces data redundancy (multiple copies of data in a single database which is hard to maintain)
- Easier data-to-schema mapping visualization
- Aids in a certain angle of Object Oriented Programming

Why Denormalize:

- Improves performance of queries
- When you have static/persistent data, why not?

If you're just about to set up your database, consider immediately the purpose of your data. Not all data need to be normalized or denormalized; you can have a hybrid. Again, that is, where applicable.

The purpose of your data is also as important as how you get your data, at least when it comes to modeling. If you are working with a highly transactional database but need half-hourly (or even shorter interval) reports you'll also have to think of data source redundancy (this time I mean having backups or replicated databases for data security as well) --then you'll decide if you need a hybrid, normalized or denormalized model for your tables. If your client, for example, requires data to be sent to them not as reports but as structured data, you'll be able to work with their need of normalized data, but that may not necessarily mean that you'll have to normalize yours --ETL may come into play, but that's after careful review and testing of transformation or query speeds. When you simply load data, say from CMS servers, and only require the records for reporting, you can denormalize your data for accessibility. The speed of your queries for static data will be visible also if you decide to aggregate data during the loading process. There's also a matter of whether you're dealing with Slowly Changing Dimensions, where your data structure is affected by a need to 'group'..

Sorry, I may have rambled off... **I would also like to emphasize again that this post is of my opinion.** I don't present these as pure, unchanging facts.. These just happen to be some of the things I've been able to learn of. Many may/will disagree with what I've written here, but ultimately, I'm just sharing my own experiences when it comes to deciding how to model your data.

Answer (score 0):

1.

1. If records you talk about are of same type (schema) then usually they are stored in same table, because splitting them into different tables have many complications with being able to query and decide where to put new records.  To speed up queries, indexes are assigned to those fields that are queried in WHERE clause.  Also you might want to spend some time building optimized queries.
2. An approach is general: you decompose your domain in such a way that each entity has its own table and for every association you have a table.
3. To measure execution time you can use [MySQL Query Analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html) .  I think phpmyadmin has measurements for query execution.
4. See indexes, query optimizations.  I think InnoDB is a bit slower, but haven't checked that in years.
5. You migt be thinking about html ripping - usually javascript is used to inject some html during page load.  That is you provide only part of the page, and js does the rest.  So html parsers break on that.  Also you can use functions to prevent sql injections.